# java regex for url css filename and extension

Tags: java, css, url

I want to get the whatevername.css from url's but I'm doing something wrong, the urls might change and the names also so it could be

www.asdasad.as/asdas/asdas/mystyles.css

asda.com/styles.css
etc etc

I've tried with this (but it doesn't work "cannot return value from method whose result is void"):

```
String fileName = "www.whateverpage.es/style.css";
int idx = fileName.replaceAll("\\", "/").lastIndexOf("/");
return idx >= 0 ? fileName.substring(idx + 1) : fileName;
```

Comment: `it doesn't work` is not a good way to describe problem. You should tell us what problem you get and if you see any exception post its stack trace. Please update your question with additional informations using [[edit]] option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`replaceAll` uses regex as parameter and to represent `\` literal in regex engine you need to pass `\\` literal so you would need to write it as `"\\\\"` String

```
int idx = fileName.replaceAll("\\\\", "/").lastIndexOf("/");
```

---

To get rid of this madness try maybe `replace('\\','/')` instead `replaceAll`. This method wont use regex, but only character switch, so your code can look like

```
int idx = fileName.replace('\\', '/').lastIndexOf("/");
```

---

Edit after your update

> cannot return value from method whose result is void

this error is caused by fact that return type of your method is `void` instead of `String`. Change your method declaration from `void yourMethodsName()` to `String yourMethodsName()`.

Comment: The problem is with the last line it says "cannot return value from  method whose result is void" but i might take in mind the replace thing

Comment: Oh, so in that case change method declaration to `String yourMethodsName()` instead `void yourMethodsName()`

Comment: No problem... nie ma sprawy :)